# Artificial delay in TCP socket with C, for race condition exploitation

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to introduce an artificial delay in a TCP socket server implemented in C.

The idea is for it to take a while for a client to connect to the server on purpose.

To implement this, I tried instead of simply using a blocking `accept()` to receive connections, polling for a waiting connection and then `sleep()`ing before `accept()`ing.

However, it seems as though data is written to some other buffer anyway, and the only effect is that it takes the `sleep()` delay for my program to read from the buffer. Meanwhile the client has happily connected and sent the data already.

Am I going about this the right way? Possibly relevant information: both client and server are connecting via loopback interface on the same virtual machine (VMWare Player).

My client code:

```
printf("Connecting to %s:18211 .. ", host); fflush(stdout);

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
sin.sin_port = htons(18211);

if(connect(fd, (void *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
  printf("Unable to connect to host %s\n", host);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define HITHERE ".oO Oo.\n"
if(write(fd, HITHERE, strlen(HITHERE)) == -1) {
  printf("Unable to write banner to host %s\n", host);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
#undef HITHERE

printf("Connected!\nSending file .. "); fflush(stdout);

ffd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
if(ffd == -1) {
  printf("Damn. Unable to open file\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Server code:

I tried doing a socket `poll()` and then sleeping before `accept()` here, but whilst data was received there was no delay in the client.

Comment: I cant see any server code. Copy&paste error?

Comment: @thuovila I had it saved in a suspended VM booted off a Live CD, it failed to resume so I've lost it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TCP handshake (SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK) happens before you get notified, at the OS level, and the client is free to send data immediately. accept() is just a server side thing giving you a fd for that specific connection.

If you want to delay establishing the connection, you should probably do in in your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I second the firewall idea, e.g. some delay for ACKs in iptables. Another thing to try might be setting the `listen()` backlog to 0 or something very small. However IIRC (though Im unsure) Linux does not set it to the number you give `listen()` so youll have to experiment to see how large it is. See how many clients connect before you call `accept()` and then add one more to be "exploited".